# How can I get data from Vuex to dayCellDidMount in fullcalendar 5?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, vuex

I do not want to use "event" or "eventSource". I want to make completely custom cells. That is, display your title from the dayCellDidMount hook. Now I get my data from the store, but they do not have time to load before the cells are initialized.

```
 renderDays (arg) {
      const editIcon = document.createElement('div')
      editIcon.classList.add('material-icons', 'calendar-edit-icon')
      editIcon.textContent = 'create'
      const title = document.createElement('div')
      const currentDateStr =
          arg.date.getFullYear() +
          '-' +
          ('0' + (arg.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
          '-' +
          ('0' + arg.date.getDate()).slice(-2)

      this.events.forEach(event => {
        if (event.start === currentDateStr) {
          title.textContent = event.title
        }
      })

      arg.el.append(editIcon)
      arg.el.append(title)
    },
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use events? It doesn't really make a lot of sense

Comment: I don't want to use events because I want to do a lot of custom things. For example, I don’t want to have a standard title. Instead, I want to make my own conditions and display what I need. Thus, I will also get rid of the need to hide the standard popup window that I do not need, duplicate functionality when clicking on the eventClick and dateClick (because I want to have the same functionality when clicked, that is, open my popup) and so on... I have already tried to do it through events and this is definitely not what I want. I want to draw everything myself, in the appropriate hook.

Comment: In general, I have already solved the problem. I just added a variable to the watch (in vue) any changes to the array from the store and changed its value when the array changed, and also added a key to the calendar for a new rendering. I don't really like this solution, but that's all I could do.

Comment: There is no "standard popup" when clicking on events or dates. I'm not sure what you're referring to. It's certainly not part of fullCalendar, maybe that's something else you've added. So that's not relevant

Comment: And for "don’t want to have a standard title. Instead, I want to make my own conditions and display what I need"...that's fine. You have the event render hooks (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) where you can alter the content and appearance of an event as much as you wish. I can't see how either of your points is really an argument for ditching the event model entirely, as far as I can see

Comment: When I talked about the standard popup, I meant the popup when I clicked on moreLinkClick. And about events ... When I work with store and events, I have to convert the data that arrives from the API for the calendar several times. After receiving and before sending. These are unnecessary actions that also complicate life a little.

Comment: It's a little annoying to transform the data I suppose but is it really worth throwing away all the functionality as a result? Or you could make the API output a better format, if you have control over it.

Comment: I see what you mean about the moreEventLink popup, that is annoying, although you can use CSS to make it go away

Comment: The point is that I don't need this functionality. All I want from a calendar is rendering the cells and working with several methods that are not related to events. It seems to me that in my case it is easier not to use events.

Comment: Ok. It's up to you. So, maybe the solution to your original problem is to delay loading the calendar until the event data has loaded?